# Proof of Wald's second identity?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

I am very confused about the last step in the proof. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}ES_{\tau}^21_{\tau>n}=0$ then use the decomposition $S_{\tau}=S_n+(S_{\tau}-S_n)$, I get $\lim_{n\to\infty}E((S_{n}^2+2S_n(S_{\tau}-S_n)+(S_{\tau}-S_n)^2)1_{\tau>n})=0$, then we need $\lim_{n\to\infty}E((2S_n(S_{\tau}-S_n)+(S_{\tau}-S_n)^2)1_{\tau>n})=0$ to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}E((S_n)^21_{\tau>n})=0$.

Then $S_n$ and $S_{\tau}-S_n$ are independent, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}E(2S_n(S_{\tau}-S_n)1_{\tau>n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}E(2S_n)E(S_{\tau}-S_n)=0$?(Not sure about this step since $\tau$ is unbounded.)

Then we still need to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}E((S_{\tau}-S_n)^2)1_{\tau>n})=0$, why the lecture note says we need to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}E((S_{\tau}-S_n))1_{\tau>n}|\mathscr{F}_n)=0$?

Comment: I think that the missing square is just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer why the note only looks at the first moment, but unless my memory has failed, wouldn't the following equality hold due to the "pull out property" and independence (for measurable maps $f$ such that $f(S_{\tau} - S_n) \in L^1$)?
$$
\Big| \Bbb{E}\big[f(S_{\tau} - S_n) 1_{\tau > n} \mid \mathcal{F}_n\big] \Big| = 1_{\tau > n} \, \Big|\Bbb{E}\big[f(S_{\tau} - S_n) \big] \Big|
$$
...if so, then this observation should work for $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = x^2$ without much mutation.