# Proof of Wald's Second Identity

Tags: probability, measure-theory, expected-value, stopping-times

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be iid random variables in $L^1$ and $T$ be a stopping time. Prove

$E(S_T-E(X_i)T)^2=Var(X_i)E(T)$.

I understand the proof when $E(X_i)=0$ but I am having difficulty for the case otherwise. I'm thinking of shifting/centering the random variable $X$ but am unsure as to how to implement this exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I long I know for centered $X_1$ the proof is along the lines of using optimal stopping, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167439/proof-of-walds-second-identity).

Define $\xi_i := X_i - \Bbb E [X_i]$. Since $\xi_1$ is centered we have (assuming we understand the centered case) that
$$\Bbb E[(S_T - \Bbb E[X_1] T)^2]= \Bbb E [(\sum_{i=1}^T X_i - \sum_{i=1}^T \Bbb E[X_i])^2] = \Bbb E[(\sum_{i=1}^T \xi_i)^2]\\ \overset{(*)}{=} \Bbb V (\xi_1) \Bbb E[T] = \Bbb V (X_i)\Bbb E[T] $$

where in $(*)$ we use the result from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167439/proof-of-walds-second-identity).

Comment: Thanks, the majority of this makes sense to me now. However, I am confused by the third equality in the final line. Is this using OST and a similar argument to the case when $E(X_i)=0$ or is this something separate?

Comment: I just wanted to present the way we can center the $X_i$ because you wrote that you understand the proof for the centered case. I added where I used the result for the centered case. Or did I get your comment wrong?

Comment: The proof I have used for when $E(X_i)=0$ is similar to the link you provided, the first half at least. I am unsure as to what is the martingale here for us to be applying the OST? Sorry if I am missing something obvious. Thanks

Comment: I think you make yourself more work than necessary. If you proved it for the centered case my answer provides a way to extend the result on non-centered ones. There is no need to adapt the proof in the link. The sum $S^\xi_T := \sum_{i=1}^T \xi_i$ is the sum which appears in the theorem in the link.